# What am I? R.I.D.?

Tags: riddle

Sometimes I look like a donut,
other times I look like a truck.
I have many shapes so you know,
but i am no shadow.

Converting from one thing to another is my technique,
but it is the very same thing that I seek.
Now you may search your garage,
though it won't be easy with my camouflage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> Transformer? (Thanks to @smriti for the idea - R.I.D = Robots In Disguise)

Sometimes I look like a donut

> Electrical transformers are often toroidal

Sometimes I look like a truck

> Optimus Prime! He's a "Transformer" that looks like a truck.

I have many shapes so you know,

> Both the robotic and electrical voltahe step up/down transformers come in many different forms

but i am no shadow.

> No idea for this one.

Converting from one thing to another is my technique,

> The robotic transformer changes shapes, and the electrical transformer changes voltage levels

but it is the very same thing that I seek.

> The electrical form changes high voltage to low voltage or vice versa (it stays voltage). The robots also remain robots, just in a different shape.

Now you may search your garage,
though it won't be easy with my camouflage.

> Robotic transformers are meant to blend in and look like normal vehicles.

Comment: nicely done!  though by converting i am hoping for an answer related to 'energy'

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> playing dough

Sometimes I look like a donut,
other times I look like a truck.
I have many shapes so you know,

> It can be molded in those shapes

but i am no shadow.

> Obviously

Converting from one thing to another is my technique,
but it is the very same thing that I seek.

> It can molded again and again from one thing to another

Now you may search your garage,
though it won't be easy with my camouflage.

> This is where I am stuck

Comment: I was searching for full forms of RID, first one I got is 'Robots In Disguise', and I think this also fits the answer :P

Comment: [Robots in Disguise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Robots_in_Disguise)